# SQL Nested Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have the following SQL Code which is not giving me my desired results.

```
SELECT
    POLICIES.CLIENTS_ID,
    POLICIES.CLIENTCODE,
    COUNT(POLICIES.POLICIES_ID) as [Total Policies],
    (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(POLICIES.POLICIES_ID) 
        FROM 
            POLICIES 
        WHERE 
            POLICIES.COVCODE = 'AUT'
    ) as [Auto Policies]

FROM
    POLICIES
    LEFT JOIN CLIENTS
        ON CLIENTS.CLIENTS_ID = POLICIES.CLIENTS_ID

WHERE
    POLICIES.CNR IS NULL

GROUP BY 
    POLICIES.CLIENTS_ID,
    POLICIES.CLIENTCODE

ORDER BY 
    POLICIES.CLIENTS_ID
```

I get a result like this:

```
ID  CODE    Total    Auto
3   ABCDE1  1        999999
4   ABCDE2  1        999999
5   ABCDE3  2        999999
6   ABCDE4  2        999999
```

I would like for the last column to COUNT the total auto policies that exists for that clientid rather than all of the auto policies that exist.  I believe I need a nested select statement that somehow groups all like results on the clientid, but it ends up returning more than 1 row and throws the error.

If I add:

```
GROUP BY 
    POLICIES.CLIENTS_ID
```

I get:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the....
```

Any help would be appreciated greatly!
Thank you

Comment: What is the relationship between `CLIENTS_ID` and `CLIENTCODE`? Is it 1 to 1 as your example results suggest? Looks like the left join on CLIENTS is entirely redundant.

Comment: Martin, you are correct.  There is a little vestigial sql in there.  I plan on expanding the data into another table shortly after this.  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CASE statement to do this. Instead of your subquery in the SELECT clause use:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN POLICIES.COVCODE = 'AUT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [AUTO POLICIES]
```

As Martin Smith pointed out. If client_id has multiple client_codes then this will give you the count of records for each combination of client_id/client_code. If client_id is 1:1 with client_code then this will give you a count of records for each distinct client_id, which I suspect is the case from your example and question.

Unrelated: You have a LEFT JOIN to your `Clients` table, but you don't use your `Clients` table anywhere int he query. Consider removing it if you don't need to select or filter by any its fields, since it's just unused overhead.

Comment: Thank you for this, I see, you are using the case statement as a counter rather than counting the rows.  Interesting logic, this works perfectly!  Thank you - as for my unused join, I will be adding data from that in the near future, good eyes.

Comment: And what about POLICIES.CNR IS NULL condition? the subquery in the question counts NOT NULL POLICIES.CNR but your SUM doesn't

Comment: This is true, @Multisync, but I'd bet that OP's intention was to have those excluded form the count as well. If it's not then a derived table would be the correct solution.

Comment: I would like to also make sure these counters are not counting when the CNR IS NULL.  Could I add an `AND` statement to the case that included `AND POLICIES.CNR IS NOT NULL`? Or does my original `WHERE` clause eliminate those already?

Comment: In that case, @evade, you are good as-is. Since the `IS NOT NULL` is in your WHERE clause and you are not doing a subquery, that condition will be applied to the data used in the CASE statement automatically.

Comment: If, for instance, you had a field you wanted to sum based on a condition then you would reference the field `CASE WHEN foo=bar THEN <field_with_your_count> ELSE 0 END`. If the logic was more complicated and wanted to get a count that wasn't affected by the conditions in your WHERE clause, you would need to build a subquery and JOIN the query in your FROM clause, then reference that subquery/derived table in your SELECT clause. So.. it depends. As is the case with most SQL requirements, there are plenty of ways to skin this cat.

Answer (score 2):

What if you modify the inner query for getting count to something like

```
SUM(CASE WHEN POLICIES.COVCODE = 'AUT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Auto Policies]
```

Comment: They are grouping by `CLIENTS_ID, CLIENTCODE` and the requirement is to count those with the same `clientid`. Might not be exactly the same number.

Comment: @MartinSmith, from OP's posted query if I have understood correct then the sole reason OP has make that count as sub select cause he wants to get the count with some condition apart from normal grouping. so this suggestion, should fetch correct result.

Comment: Seems like they are happy with it!